# OrderedTest- Not keeping values from previous Test. - visualstudio208 - Unit Testing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, automated-tests

I am trying to Unit Test the application using VSTS 2008 unit Testing.
My Problem is:
I want to invoke two test case in an order.
I am using the ordered Test case feature of VSTS 2008 for this.
Problem i facing is I increment the value of one variable(X) in TestA and on the basis of that value i am chekcing something in TestB.
But when the control comes into TestB, I get the initial value of the X but not that which was incremented in TestA.
I think for every test vsts create a new instance of the test class in memory.
Please suggest a solution to this except use of STATIC variables.

Code for the same is as below

```
   [TestMethod()]
   public void ff()
    {
        i = 11;
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void gg()
    {
        if (i == 4)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("it is 4");
        }

        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("it is 7");
        }
    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to redesign your tests in a way that each one can be run separately?  This is the correct way to test in 99% of cases.  While it does increase overhead a bit, and you may be duplicating your setup a bit, it is far easier to maintain, and each test can focus on it's single function, without worrying about environmental changes.

Answer (score 0):

run your orderedtests using the TestView window under Test>Windows.

clicking run all tests in the solution will cause your orderedtests to run out of order